# How do I fix my outlines?

Tags: toon-shading

I am making a model of a TV man; I have decided to use a toon shader. This particular toon shader worked for me on another model, so I thought it would work fine with my TV man model, but the outline only seems to be working on some parts of the mesh. I separated the mesh into different parts and the issue persisted. I would like to know how to fix this issue.

Here is the tutorial I used for the toon shader: [Toon Shader](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qs4QUGKm6XU&t=151s&pp=ygUTdG9vbiBzaGFkZXIgYmxlbmRlcg%3D%3D)

Here is the model I am using:
[image: picture of the model's parts]

Here is the blender file: [Model](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LH8UIGZQHFZ57B0haCnZCRbztg_JtPqW/view?usp=drive_link)

Comment: Have you checked if all face normals are pointing in the correct direction? Like using _Face Orientation_ in the _Overlays_ to show if they are all blue? Or going into _Edit Mode_, selecting all with `A`, then `Shift`+`N` to recalculate the normals?

Comment: This is 'Inverted Hull' outlining.. I think we need to see the topology of your original objects, and what the _Solidify_ looks like, plain and simple, without flipped normals and the dark material. Possibilities include incorrect normals on the original, or split edges.. if you share on https://blend-exchange.com/, we can have a look